# Django REST Framework: Why Adding IsAuthenticated Permissions Only Threw 500 Internal Error Instead of 401 / 403 Errors?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, auth0, django-rest-framework-jwt

My original backend API based off Django REST Framework was working without any security measures implemented.

Now I am implementing a JWT Token Authentication process, but realised the ever-bugging problem on the backend-Django side was that once I have added "IsAuthenticated" to "**'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ( 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated')**" , the page that is thrown from Django is consistently a 500 Internal Error, instead of a 401/403 Authenticated Error, of which I may at least know how to move forward in resolving.

Thus, I hope someone can help to point me some direction in resolving it.

---

I have been trying for the last 5-days to implement a JWT Token, Machine-to-Machine verification, with zero-user account, and purely based on a Token authorization access, and have sort-of sorted out most of the front-end request access process via Auth0.

The process by which I presumed works based on what I have read from Auth0 API:

1. Client Browser sends request to Auth0 token authentication API
2. Auth0 replies with Token
3. Client Browser uses replied Token to send as Authorization Header to backend API
4. Server API replies with result data.

---

The current problem I do realised is that upon Step 4, is that my server kept throwing 500 Errors instead of 401/403 Errors.

I am quite unsure where I may have gone wrong and hope someone may provide some assistance to add code to help throw an Authenticated-Error response.

---

***SETTINGS.PY***

```
import json
from six.moves.urllib import request
from cryptography.x509 import load_pem_x509_certificate
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend


INSTALLED_APPS = [

    # Third-Party Apps
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_jwt',

]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        # GLOBAL SETTINGS SETUP FOR "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES"
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', 
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        # GLOBAL SETTINGS SETUP FOR "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES"
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': (
        # GLOBAL SETTINGS SETUP FOR "EXCEPTION_HANDLER"
        'rest_framework.views.exception_handler',
    ),
}


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
]



AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
]



AUTH0_DOMAIN = os.environ.get('AUTH0_DOMAIN')
API_IDENTIFIER = os.environ.get('API_IDENTIFIER')
PUBLIC_KEY = os.environ.get('PUBLIC_KEY')
JWT_ISSUER = os.environ.get('ISSUER')

# If AUTH0_DOMAIN is defined, load the jwks.json
if AUTH0_DOMAIN:
    jsonurl = request.urlopen('https://' + AUTH0_DOMAIN + '/.well-known/jwks.json')
    jwks = json.loads(jsonurl.read())
    cert = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' + jwks['keys'][0]['x5c'][0] + '\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----'
    certificate = load_pem_x509_certificate(cert.encode('utf-8'), default_backend())
    PUBLIC_KEY = certificate.public_key()
    JWT_ISSUER = 'https://' + AUTH0_DOMAIN + '/'

# JWT settings
JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USERNAME_HANDLER':
        'backend.user.jwt_get_username_from_payload_handler',   # REDIRECT TO "backend.user" INSTEAD OF "auth0authorization.user"
    'JWT_PUBLIC_KEY': PUBLIC_KEY,
    'JWT_ALGORITHM': 'RS256',
    'JWT_AUDIENCE': API_IDENTIFIER,
    'JWT_ISSUER': JWT_ISSUER,
    'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'Bearer',

    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
}
```

***VIEWS.PY***

```
class TestsViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Job.objects.all()
    serializer_class = JobsSerializer
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, )
    http_method_names = ['get']
```

***SETTINGS.PY***

```
Django==1.11.21
django-cors-headers==3.0.0
djangorestframework==3.9.4
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
```

Comment: 500 is a server error. If the `DEBUG` is on, that should produce more than just 500 error code, there must be some error message.

Comment: Hi @bloodwithmilk,

The error is a standard:

```
TypeError at /api/test/
'list' object is not callable
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/test/
Django Version: 1.11.21
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
'list' object is not callable
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py in handle_exception, line 452
Python Executable: /usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7
Python Version: 2.7.16
```

Answer (score 2):

I have just officially identified my own mistake and it was just clearly a noob mistake where a Typo was the main concern.

I went through a granular-attempt to debug and attempted to use "print()" to check on potential variables which I thought might be a cause issue to the problem.

Ended up, I had found that the key issue was due to the following where:

- WORKING CODE --- **AUTH0_DOMAIN = os.environ.get('JWT_AUTH0_DOMAIN')**
- ERROR CODE --- **AUTH0_DOMAIN = os.environ.get('AUTH0_DOMAIN')**

---

I sincerely believe this is a mistake that all developers will make and I for once will clearly miss out the typo error as the code does sound logical to me.

What I would suggest to others is that if you are, like me, am using a .env file to keep all these variables, use a "print()" function, like "**print("AUTH0_DOMAIN-----: %r" % AUTH0_DOMAIN)**" to test out the potential areas of problem that channels to the result of your code.

From my experience, I do presume that the 500 error thrown in my case, was due that the server is just unable to "reply" a result, as the "AUTH0_DOMAIN" variable is suppose to provide a url. And the code that follows, as shown below:

```
AUTH0_DOMAIN = os.environ.get('JWT_AUTH0_DOMAIN')
API_IDENTIFIER = os.environ.get('JWT_API_IDENTIFIER')
PUBLIC_KEY = os.environ.get('PUBLIC_KEY')
JWT_ISSUER = os.environ.get('ISSUER')

if AUTH0_DOMAIN:
    jsonurl = request.urlopen('https://' + AUTH0_DOMAIN + '/.well-known/jwks.json')
    jwks = json.loads(jsonurl.read())
    cert = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' + jwks['keys'][0]['x5c'][0] + '\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----'
    certificate = load_pem_x509_certificate(cert.encode('utf-8'), default_backend())
    PUBLIC_KEY = certificate.public_key()
    JWT_ISSUER = 'https://' + AUTH0_DOMAIN + '/'
```

Apparently, the above code, with a "None" returned by "AUTH0_DOMAIN", still allowed it to work smoothly, up until the two key lines of codes are applied:

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
       'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', 
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
```

So, my solution is as long as there is a valid URL passed through in "AUTH0_DOMAIN", the overall process will work perfectly.

Hope this will help save another soul and save them from the 7-days of attempts I have lost from mine. Cheers!